# android - ANR on taking picture from gallery/camera

Tags: android, android-camera, gallery, android-anr-dialog

Did someone face the issue when ANR happened after choosing picture from gallery or taking a photo from camera (in my case it returns byte[] array to my app)?

How to solve it?

**Upd.** Here's the code how an image is picked. But this part of code didn't change and some time ago it worked (some other parts of code were changed, I don't know if it's important).

```
void chooseOrTakePhotoDialog(OnActivityResultListener listener) {
    onActivityResultListener = listener;
    final CharSequence[] items = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Library", "Cancel" };
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Add Photo");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
            } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),
                        SELECT_FILE);
            } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

interface OnActivityResultListener {
    void onPhotoByteArray(byte[] bytes);
}
private OnActivityResultListener onActivityResultListener;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.wtf("onActivityResult", "req="+requestCode+" res="+resultCode+" data="+data);
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CAMERA:
            if (onActivityResultListener != null) {
                Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                onActivityResultListener.onPhotoByteArray(stream.toByteArray());
            }
            break;
        case SELECT_FILE:
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            try {
                byte[] bytes = Helper.readBytes(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
                onActivityResultListener.onPhotoByteArray(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code please and the error.

Comment: it's strange but no error in Logs... it just freezes and then closes (but some time ago it worked, with the same code for picking; I changed some other things)

Comment: Why are you returning it in byte array? May I know the reason?

Comment: @SripadRaj idk, it was my teammate's desicion. Later it turned out that a photo should be sent to the server only on the following activity and passing byte[] array solves this problem. But idk why he initially made it return byte[]

Comment: can you show some code how you're doing that?

Comment: @SripadRaj ok, I'll update the question

Comment: @SripadRaj updated

Comment: do not convert the data to byte array right away in `onActivityResult()`. I guess the conversion in the activity result is taking time, so you will be stuck with unresponsive app. I suggest you to get the bitmap data, convert it before sending it to server.

Comment: @SripadRaj and how to make Bitmap in SELECT_FILE case?

Answer (score 0):

For the case of `SELECT_FILE`, you can try getting `Bitmap` like below.

```
 case SELECT_FILE:
            if (data != null) {
                try {
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                    Cursor c = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(
                            selectedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
                    c.moveToFirst();
                    int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
                    String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
                    c.close();
                    Bitmap thumbnail = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath); 

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
```

Comment: Thanx! so it's faster than converting to byte[]?

Comment: Converting in `onActivityResult()` will consume time or cause ANR. That is why I suggested you to get the bitmap first before sending it to server, convert it to byte array, and then send it to server.

Comment: and what's the difference between doing it in `onActivityResult()` or later?